# ¿Como puedo recorrer una lista dentro de otra lista y cambiar un valor de esta según determinadas condiciones en Python?

Tags: python

¡Hola! Mi duda es la siguiente. Supongamos que tengo la siguiente lista:

```
lista1=[['rojo', 'amarillo', 'coche'],['verde','azul','furgoneta']]
```

O bien supongamos la siguiente, ya que no sé el orden de las sublistas:

```
lista2=[['verde','azul','furgoneta'],['rojo', 'amarillo', 'coche']]
```

Ahora lo que querría hacer es decirle al programa que si la posición 2 de una de las sublistas es 'coche', cambie la posición uno por 'naranja'.

Es decir, que recorra cada una de las sublistas y en todas las que la posición 2 sea 'coche', la posición 1 pase a ser 'naranja'.

Cabe decir que yo no sé la posición de la sublista que contiene 'coche', igual que en el ejemplo está en la posición 0 podría estar en la posición 8.

He probado con combinaciones de for pero no lo he conseguido.

El resultado que esperaría en el caso de la lista 1 sería:

```
[['rojo', 'naranja', 'coche'],['verde','azul','furgoneta']]
```

Mientras que en la lista 2 el resultado esperado sería este:

```
[['verde','azul','furgoneta'],['rojo', 'naranja', 'coche']]
```

Es decir, busco una función "universal" para que se cambie la posición 1 de la lista que tenga "coche" en posición 2, este la sublista en cualquier posición de la lista principal.

Muchas gracias de antemano a quién consiga resolverme la duda, un saludo :)

Answer (score 2):

Ya que buscas algo "universal", puedes crearte una función que permita mapear cualquier lista del tamaño que sea y sustituir uno o múltiples valores en determinadas posiciones si se cumple que en una o varias posiciones los valores son iguales a unos proporcionados.

Con unos cuantos `for` y la ayuda de `zip` y `enumerate` puedes conseguir algo como:

```
def modificar_items(lista, valores_actuales=[], valores_nuevos=[]):
    for i, sublista, in enumerate(lista):
        if all(item_act is None or item_act == item_list
               for item_list, item_act in zip(sublista, valores_actuales)):
            for j, item_nuevo in enumerate(valores_nuevos):
                if item_nuevo is not None:
                    lista[i][j] = item_nuevo
```

Ejemplos de uso:

> ```
> lista1 = [['rojo', 'amarillo', 'coche'],
>           ['rojo','azul','furgoneta'],
>           ['negro', 'blanco', 'coche']]
>
> modificar_items(lista1, [None, None, "coche"], [None, "naranja", None])
>
> [['rojo', 'naranja', 'coche'],
>  ['rojo', 'azul', 'furgoneta'],
>  ['negro', 'naranja', 'coche']]
> ```

---

> ```
> lista1 = [['rojo', 'amarillo', 'coche'],
>           ['rojo','azul','furgoneta'],
>           ['negro', 'blanco', 'coche']]
>
> modificar_items(lista1, ["negro", None, "coche"], [None, "naranja", None])
>
> [['rojo', 'amarillo', 'coche'],
>  ['rojo', 'azul', 'furgoneta'],
>  ['negro', 'naranja', 'coche']]
> ```

---

> ```
> lista1 = [['rojo', 'amarillo', 'coche'],
>           ['rojo','azul','furgoneta'],
>           ['negro', 'blanco', 'coche']]
>
> modificar_items(lista1, ["rojo", None, None], [None, "violeta", None])
>
> [['rojo', 'violeta', 'coche'],
>  ['rojo', 'violeta', 'furgoneta'],
>  ['negro', 'blanco', 'coche']]
> ```

---

> ```
> lista1 = [['rojo', 'amarillo', 'coche'],
>           ['rojo','azul','furgoneta'],
>           ['negro', 'blanco', 'coche']]
>
> modificar_items(lista1, [None, None, None], ["magenta", "violeta", None])
> [['magenta', 'violeta', 'coche'],
>  ['magenta', 'violeta', 'furgoneta'],
>  ['magenta', 'violeta', 'coche']]
> ```

Comment: ¡Hola! Gracias por tu ayuda, pero me da el siguiente error: "zip argument #1 must support iteration". ¿Sabrías por qué? ¡Gracias!

Comment: Eso pasa porque tienes un item en tu lista que no es otra lista, por ejemplo: `lista1 = [['rojo', 'amarillo', 'coche'], 13]`. ¿Tu lista no es siempre una lista de listas como muestras en tu pregunta? Por cierto ¿usas Python 2?

Comment: La he llamado tal y como me has puesto en el ejemplo. Uso Python 3.7

Comment: Samuel, he modificado el comentario de arriba, miralo, tienes items en la lista que no son listas, mas exactamente, no son iterables). No es por contradecirte, pero el error que muestras es en principio de Python 2, asegurate de no estar usando el intérptrete incorrecto. Puedes asegurarte agregando al inicio de tu script esto: `import sys;print("Intérprete: ", sys.executable)` y mira que imprime. Puedes ver el código funcionando online si quieres: https://repl.it/repls/PreciousHeartyPipelining

Comment: He añadido la línea que me has dicho y me imprime lo siguiente: Intérprete:  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\python.exe. Ahora que estoy revisando quizás el problema sea que va relacionado con una clase, pues la lista que a la que quería aplicar la función se crea así: animalesG.append(Animal(nombre, fecha, tipo, estado, id)), donde Animal es una clase

Comment: Entonces **no tienes una lista de listas como en la pregunta**, tienes una lista de objetos `Animal`, en la que seguro que no has implementado `__getitem__` para permitir el indizado ni el protocolo iterador. No obstante, la aproximación debería ser otra, puedes filtrar usando los atributos. Creo que modificar la pregunta sería poco oportuno dado que ya hay dos respuestas para ella. Considera crear otra, es similar el problema, pero hay que abordarlo de otra forma. Agrega la clase de ser posible.

Comment: De acuerdo, muchas gracias. Como ves estoy un poco hecho un lío, más tarde crearé una pregunta nueva para ello. Disculpa las molestias por el malentendido.

Answer (score 1):

En primer lugar, un error de comprensión XD, entendía posición 2, como la posición a nivel de razonamiento digamos, que en la lista1 seria "amarillo", en este caso, te refieres a posición 2, pero del arreglo, que seria la posición 3 desde el punto de vista de razonamiento.

Modificando la respuesta simplemente se cambiaria `posicion_de_cambio` por 1 y la posición de búsqueda por 2

Para recorrer la lista:

```
lista_principal = [['rojo', 'amarillo', 'coche'],['verde','azul','furgoneta']]

# sub_lista sera cada una de las listas que están dentro de la lista principal
for sub_lista in lista_principal:
    # elemento sera cada elemento de cada sub_lista.
    for elemento in sub_lista :
        print(elemento)

"""
rojo
amarillo
coche
verde
azul
furgoneta
"""
```

Para validar la posición y realizar el cambio de valores

```
# creamos las variables necesarias.
posicion_de_cambio = 1 # que posición se cambiara
posicion_de_busqueda = 2 # en que posición debe buscarla
buscar = "coche" # que valor debe encontrar
cambiar = "naranja" # por cual valor lo cambiara

# enumerate enumera los objetos de una lista, 
# devolviendo el indice o posición de la misma, empezando desde el cero.
# este indice debe incluirse en el for
for indice, elemento in enumerate(sub_lista):
    # verificamos la posición de búsqueda
    if indice == posicion_de_busqueda:
        # verificamos el valor
        if elemento == buscar:
            # lo cambiamos accediendo a la posición de cambio 
            # en la sub_lista que estamos recorriendo
            sub_lista[posicion_de_cambio] = cambiar
```

Tendríamos al final esto

```
posicion_de_cambio = 1
posicion_de_busqueda = 2
buscar = "coche"
cambiar = "naranja"

lista_principal = [['rojo', 'amarillo', 'coche'],['verde','azul','furgoneta']]

for sub_lista in lista_principal:
    for indice, elemento in enumerate(sub_lista):
      if indice == posicion_de_busqueda:
          if elemento == buscar:
              sub_lista[posicion_de_cambio] = cambiar

print(lista_principal)
```

Resultado:

```
[['rojo', 'naranja', 'coche'],['verde','azul','furgoneta']]
```

Para lista2:

```
[['verde', 'azul', 'furgoneta'], ['rojo', 'naranja', 'coche']]
```

Comment: Hola! Agradezco mucho tu respuesta, pero quizás no me he expresado bien. En el ejemplo la sublista que contiene 'coche' está en la posición 0, pero la cosa es que yo no sé en que posicion está la sublista que contiene 'coche', ahí está el problema.

Comment: @SamuelMartinez creo que lo hiciste peor en el comentario jajaja. La primer sublista esta en la posicion 0, y coche esta en la posicion 3 de esa sublista.

Tu quieres recorrer cada sublista, y ver si en ellas la posicion 2 tiene el valor "coche", si es asi, en esa misma lista pones el valor de "naranja" en la posición 1 no?.

Podrías agregar a tu pregunta una variable con el resultado esperado del proceso para ayudar a entender que quieres lograr.

Comment: Acabo de actualizar mi pregunta. Disculpa si no me estoy expresando bien y gracias de nuevo :)

Comment: @SamuelMartinez Listo hermano, un error de comprensión XD, pensé que posición 2 se refería al segundo elemento de la lista, mas no a la posición 2 del arreglo.

Comment: @SamuelMartinez recuerda que si la respuesta fue acertada para resolver tu pregunta puedes votar la pregunta como correcta, pulsando en el check que esta al lado izquierdo del inicio de la pregunta, de esta manera, si alguien mas tiene este problema sabría a que solución posible dirigirse :D muchas gracias